# Need help with the integral for this inverse Fourier transform.

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I need to calculate the following inverse Fourier transform:

$$G(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} {\int _{- \infty} ^{+ \infty}} \dfrac{1 - e^{-i \omega T}}{i \omega} \; e^{i \omega t} \, \mathrm{d} \omega$$

with $T \in \mathrm{R}_+$

Now, the solution is supposed to be

$$ G(t) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \left( \mathrm{sign}(t) - \mathrm{sign}(t - T) \right)$$

but I've idea of how to get there.

Comment: Use `\displaystyle` to make the symbols bigger; by default, it's small, to fit in-line.

Comment: Better yet, use `$$ ... $$` instead of `$ ... $`

Comment: Hint: differentiate w.r.t to $t$

Comment: I tried writing $G(t) = G(T) \; + \; \frac{\mathrm{d} G}{\mathrm{d}t} |_{t = T} (t-T)$, but I went nowhere